# Получения ID только что созданного канала Discord JS

Tags: discord

`` console.log(mess.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === `report-${i}`)) ``

При выполнении именно этой части кода мне выводит undefined
Канал создается чуть выше, но его ID я получить не могу. Если канал с таким названием УЖЕ есть, то ID выводит без всяких проблем

Кто может помочь?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, канал не находится в кеше каналов данного сервера. Попробуйте данную конструкцию:

```js
let reportChannel = mess.guild.channels.resolve({ name: `report-${i}` });

console.log(channel);
```